# not compiling all classes into dll

Tags: c#, dll

I have a solution in c# that contains few projects, and I want to add a reference on one project to another, but after I add, the project that I add the reference to does not detect all the classes from this dll. It seems that not all the classes are compiling into to the dll.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Are you using project references or are you referencing the dll?

Comment: You're sure those classes are public?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the classes `public` so that they can be used by other projects.

If that doesn't help, try rebuilding the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is that the class file is not being included for compilation.

In Visual Studio, make sure the file's Build Action property is set to Compile.

Comment: Turns out this can happen by accident if you drag a class file from one project to another within the solution... the copy it creates is changed to "Content" from "Compile".

Answer (score 3):

Classes in referenced projects should have explicit modifier "public".

Answer (score 0):

Top-level classes default to "internal" access, so are only available to types in the same assembly (dll). Most like some of your types include "public" (and are thus available), and some do not (so aren't available).

You should also check you have all necessary "using" directives in the files that want to consume the types.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Make sure the classes are defined "public".  Classes, by default, are internal.

[MSDN Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt.aspx)

Comment: No, you are not correct, classes are not `private` – this has no sense, as no one can use them. For this reason `private` modifier is not valid for top-level types. They are `internal` by default, the same is stated in the articled you've provided.

Comment: @Vladislav Thanks for the clarification - I must have read too fast and mixed it up the paragraph below. I edited my answer to have the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem: I had two DLLs the one dll referenced the other: The Other dll was Framework 4.5.2, the One 3.5... Those must be the same.
I set them both to 3.5 (needed for Unity3D, since that is what I am working on)
Then it build with no insidents.